# String contain doesn't read all string in an array when break is called

Tags: android, string, loops

So I have a method that lets me use data from another activity. In this method, Data taken from another activity is use to filter a RecyclerView. So its working fine and all but the problem is when I use Break to stop a loop it also stop reading other Strings in my String array.

for example a have a String array called size and inside this array there are 10 Strings.

When the method is executed, String value that was taken from another activity will be use in String contain to determine if it matches any string in the String size[]. So the problem now is that if there are two or more Strings that matches the  String value it will only get the first one it matches and exit the loop.

So can anyone of you help in this problem because I don't what im doing wrong.

Here is the code for the method

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_pet);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        pethair=intent.getStringExtra("hair");
        petsize=intent.getStringExtra("size");
        petweight=intent.getStringExtra("weight");
        petcolor=intent.getStringExtra("color");
        results=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.find_pet_results);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.findpet_recyclerview);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.findpet_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        refresh();
        viewResult(pethair,petsize,petweight,petcolor);
        if(adapter.getItemCount()==0)
        {
            results.setText("It seem no pet matches your search..");
            Toast.makeText(find_pet.this,"Nothing matches your search",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


public void viewResult(String hair, String size, String weight, String color)
    {

        hair=hair.toLowerCase();
        size=size.toLowerCase();
        weight=weight.toLowerCase();
        color=color.toLowerCase();
        new_list=new ArrayList<>();
        for(findpet_getItems items:arrayList)
        {
            String newHair=items.getHair().toLowerCase();
            String newSize=items.getSize().toLowerCase();
            String newWeight=items.getWeight().toLowerCase();
            String newColor=items.getColor().toLowerCase();

            if(newHair.contains(hair) && newSize.contains(size)&& newWeight.contains(weight)
                && newColor.contains(color))
            {
                new_list.add(items);
                break;
            }
 }
        arrayList.clear();
        adapter.filterSearch(new_list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

}

Comment: What happens if you remove `break`?

Comment: list wont have totally unique items..

Comment: he wants totally unique items list ..dont know why..

Comment: @Deniro... you should start with how to test your code; implement stdout print statements here and there. This gives you insight in what you're doing where and learn to answer the `How` question. By changing the code you learn to answer the `Why` question. As I read you question... it reads to me "grabbed a scripts from the web", tweaked it minute and tossed a question here in the hope we code for you. If you show below your code your "tries" with error code... then 1) you show good effort & 2) others get excited and help accelerate your learning-curve and get you out of the woods much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of break do sumthing like this `for(int j= 0;j<new_list.size(); j++) { if(new_list.get(j).getHair().toLowerCase().matches(new_hair) || new_list.get(j).getSize().toLowerCase().matches(new_size) || new........) { break;} i( j == new_list.size()-1)  new_list.add(items);}`

Answer (score 0):

In For loop no need to break because only match data that time items object store in newarray list.

```
        for(findpet_getItems items:arrayList) {
            if (items.getHair().contains(hair) && items.getSize().contains(size) && items.getWeight().contains(weight)
                    && items.getColor().contains(color)) {
                new_list.add(items);
            }
        }
```